# Python: How do I check if something in a string is right

Tags: python, string, variables, pi

I am pretty new to python, sorry if I sound extremely stupid

So, instead of checking every single digit in a string, can you then check if some of it is right? Here is an example

```
pianswer = input ("What is pi?")
if pianswer == "3.14":
print ("That is correct")
```

So if somebody can do a longer version of pi, instead of doing something looking like this:

```
pianswer = input ("What is pi?")
if pianswer == "3.14":
    print ("That is correct")
elif pianswer == "3.141592":
    print ("That is correct")
elif pianswer == "3.1415":
    print ("That is correct
```

Can I then do something that just knows pi with like 50 digits and then checks if some of it is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could import `pi` from `math`, convert it to a string, and check if it starts with the user's input:

```
from math import pi

pianswer = input ("What is pi?")
if str(pi).startswith(pianswer):
    print ("That is correct")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

pi = str(math.pi)

answer = input("What is pi? ")

if pi == answer:
    print("You got it right, well, based on how many digits I know.")
elif pi.startswith(answer):
    print("The digits you put in are right, but I know more!")
elif answer.startswith("pi"):
    print("You put in more digits than I know, but the ones I know are right!")
else:
    print("Nope, that's wrong.")
```